# update specific map with multiple condition in mongo array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
{
    "dictID" : "37528e10-6344-4d93-8a57-35af0bdb6b34",
    "dictVersion" : 1,
    "addMeasures" : [ 
        {
            "measureId" : "f229ba18-0de8-47a1-8a87-88c95edd536a",
            "userId" : "3966C3DD-8328-4F18-A061-02A01111763A",
            "created" : "2017-01-07T05:47:22.512Z",
            "ownerAction" : "NA"
        }
    ],
    "deleteMeasures" : [ 
        {
            "measureId" : "0b701469-1502-4de4-95de-1ee70ad6c577",
            "userId" : "3966C3DD-8328-4F18-A061-02A01111763A",
            "created" : "2017-01-07T05:47:35.193Z",
            "ownerAction" : "NA"
        }, 
        {
            "measureId" : "443d1b97-95ae-4410-9302-da3edbad4004",
            "userId" : "3966C3DD-8328-4F18-A061-02A01111763A",
            "created" : "2017-01-07T05:47:36.062Z",
            "ownerAction" : "NA"
        }, 
        {
            "measureId" : "aa1689c9-8df6-4bff-88a4-274a4f2dc2aa",
            "userId" : "3966C3DD-8328-4F18-A061-02A01111763A",
            "created" : "2017-01-07T05:47:37.075Z",
            "ownerAction" : "NA"
        }
    ]
}
```

Above is my mongo collection and i want to do the following query:

```
db.getCollection('DataDictionaryReview').update(
    {
        $and: [
            { dictID: "37528e10-6344-4d93-8a57-35af0bdb6b34" },
            { dictVersion: 1 },
            { "deleteMeasures.measureId": "aa1689c9-8df6-4bff-88a4-274a4f2dc2aa" },
            { "deleteMeasures.ownerAction": "NA" }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        $set: {
            "deleteMeasures.$.created": "2017-01-07T06:51:56.983Z",        
            "deleteMeasures.$.ownerAction": "Reject"
        }
    }
)
```

I want to update the last map of `deleteMeasures` but every time the query is updating first map of `deleteMeasures`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is strange, the query looks okay to me, however I think it needs $elemMatch to get the correct index value.

```
db.getCollection('DataDictionaryReview').update(
    {
            dictID: "37528e10-6344-4d93-8a57-35af0bdb6b34",
            dictVersion: 1 ,
            "deleteMeasures" : { $elemMatch : {"measureId": "aa1689c9-8df6-4bff-88a4-274a4f2dc2aa", "ownerAction": "NA" }}
    }, 
    {
        $set: {
            "deleteMeasures.$.created": "2017-01-07T06:51:56.983Z",        
            "deleteMeasures.$.ownerAction": "Reject"
        }
    }
)
```